# (JS) Custom, inheritable, namespace to call controllers in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, namespaces

I am currently trying to wrap my head around creating a JavaScript namespace for organizing our JS files, that can be used to access specific methods that allow calling methods from MVC controllers. My confusion revolves around namespacing and inheriting the or applying the namespace when it is called in a different source.

**Namespace TEST.js**

```
var TEST = TEST || {}; // Needed?
(function() {
    if (typeof String.prototype.trimLeft !== "function") {
        String.prototype.trimLeft = function () {
            return this.replace(/^\s+/, "");
        };
    }
    if (typeof String.prototype.trimRight !== "function") {
        String.prototype.trimRight = function () {
            return this.replace(/\s+$/, "");
        };
    }
    if (typeof Array.prototype.map !== "function") {
        Array.prototype.map = function (callback, thisArg) {
            for (var i = 0, n = this.length, a = []; i < n; i++) {
                if (i in this) a[i] = callback.call(thisArg, this[i]);
            }
            return a;
        };
    }

this.Settings = {
    Timer: 300
};

this.Service = (name, isApi) => {
    let location = isApi === true ? "~/Controller/api/" + name : "~/Controller/" + name;

    this.Call = (data, method, type, callback) => {
        let method = location + "/" + method + ".cs";
        let data = typeof data === "object" ? data : {};
        let type = type || "GET";

        callback = fetch(method, {
            method: type,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => console.log(data));

        return callback;
    };
};

this.Functions = {
    PageWidth: function () {
        // return parseInt main container css width
    },
    setCookie: function (name, value) {
        var val = value + ";domain=" + window.location.host + ";path=/;";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + val;
    },
    deleteCookie: (name) => { document.cookie = name + "=null;domain=" + window.location.host + ";path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1900 00:00:00 GMT;"; },
    getCookie: (name) => { getCookies()[name]; },
    getCookies: () => {
        var c = document.cookie, v = 0, cookies = {};

        if (document.cookie.match(/^\s*\$Version=(?:"1"|1);\s*(.*)/)) {
            c = RegExp.$1;
            v = 1;
        }

        if (v === 0) {
            c.split(/[,;]/).map(function (cookie) {
                var parts = cookie.split(/=/, 2),
                    name = decodeURIComponent(parts[0].trimLeft()),
                    value = parts.length > 1 ? decodeURIComponent(parts[1].trimRight()) : null;
                cookies[name] = value;
            });
        } else {
            c.match(/(?:^|\s+)([!#$%&'*+\-.0-9A-Z^`a-z|~]+)=([!#$%&'*+\-.0-9A-Z^`a-z|~]*|"(?:[\x20-\x7E\x80\xFF]|\\[\x00-\x7F])*")(?=\s*[,;]|$)/g).map(function ($0, $1) {
                var name = $0,
                    value = $1.charAt(0) === '"'
                        ? $1.substr(1, -1).replace(/\\(.)/g, "$1")
                        : $1;
                cookies[name] = value;
            });
        }
        return cookies;
    },
    getQSParams: (query) => {
        query
            ? (/^[?#]/.test(query) ? query.slice(1) : query)
                .split('&')
                .reduce((params, param) => {
                    let [key, value] = param.split('=');
                    params[key] = value ? decodeURIComponent(value.replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : '';
                    return params;
                }, {}
                )
            : {}
    }
}
this.ClientState = {};
this.getWidth = function () {
    return Math.max(
        document.body.scrollWidth,
        document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
        document.body.offsetWidth,
        document.documentelement.offsetWidth,
        document.documentElement.clientWidth
    );
}
this.getHeight = function () {
    return Math.max(
        document.body.scrollHeight,
        document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        document.body.offsetHeight,
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        document.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
}
}).apply(ELITE); // Var up top go here instead?
```

And my testing code to see if this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Content/Scripts/TEST.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var test = new TEST.Service("TestController", true);
        var data = {};
        test.Call(data, "TestMethod", "GET", function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        });
    }(TEST));
</script>
```

I am sure it is something simple or a mix-up of things.

Question: Correctly namespacing a JS file to be inherited by other JS files or JS script calls for calling MVC controller methods?

Bonus: Would this be better executed as a class instead? I do have access to using ES5/ES6 and of course jQuery will be minified in with this TEST.js file!

Comment: you need to set `this` in you definitions if you're not using a module. using `new` on a wrapper function is the simplest way to do that, since it avoids touching existing code.

Comment: Oh? Example please, I am genuinely curious. Also, does this approach look feasible that I am trying to go with or do you see it being prone to bigger issues that I might be overlooking? Thanks!

Comment: actually, you'r already tacking on the methods to `ELITE`, so `TEST.Service` should be `ELITE.Service`. I'm not sure where either are defined. or you could change `.apply(ELITE)` to `.apply(TEST)`. It's a bit of an unconventional pattern, but there's nothing wrong with it. Classes might be more readable or maintainable. Look into `Object.assign` as well, it can give you a lot of flexibility for a small one-time (startup) overhead.

Comment: I meant to type TEST earlier and have edited the answer and code for clarity.

The issue I am having is on compile, when I load this page, it can't find TEST. Nor can it find a constructor for TEST called "Services". Though I thought binding this.Services would allow it to be invoked and used.

Corrections?